# Explaining an integral without integrating

Tags: calculus, integration

> The $x$ and $y$ coordinates in the figure add to $r\cos\theta+r\sin\theta=$_____. Without integrating explain why $\int_0^\frac\pi2\frac{d\theta}{(\cos\theta+\sin\theta)^2}=1$.
>   [image: Triangle]

In the figure, the base length seems to be $1$, but the question does not say anything about its height. If its height is also $1$, we can say that the blank in the question is $1$ ($\because \frac y1=\frac{1-x}1$). But explaining that the integral equals one without integrating seems difficult. $\cos\theta+\sin\theta=\frac1r$ so $(\cos\theta+\sin\theta)^2=\frac1{r^2}$. The integral equals $\int_0^\frac\pi2r^2d\theta$. At $\theta=0$ or $\frac\pi2$, $r^2=1$, so the integral should be greater than $2$. Why is it equal to $1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we have a triangle, we can calculate the area by the following formula:

$$\mathcal{A}={1\over2}ab\sin\theta$$

where $a$ and $b$ are two sides and $\theta$ the angle between them. In this case $a=b=r$ because if we have an infinitesimal angle $(\theta\to0)$ we can think $a\approx b=r$, besides when $\theta\to0$ then $\sin\theta\approx\theta$ $(d\theta)$, thus ${1\over2}ab\sin\theta\approx{1\over2}r^2d\theta$.

So in the integral, $r^2d\theta$ is the the area of the infinitesimal triangle (see shaded area in the figure above) multiplied by $2$, hence if we add up all the areas we get ${1\over2}$ i.e. the area of the "big" triangle and multiplying by $2$ we have the result.